# Quadratic form inequality

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms

Let $A$ and $B$ be symmetric, positive definite $N\times N$ matrices. Define $a_n$ as the $n$-th column of $A$ and $a_{n,n}$ as the $n,n$-th element of $A$. I'd like to show that

$$\left[\frac{a_n^T}{a_{n,n}}\left(A-\frac{a_n a_n^T}{a_{n,n}}+B\right)^{-1}\frac{a_n^T}{a_{n,n}}\right]^{-1}\leq b_{n,n}$$

where $b_{n,n}$ is the $n,n$-th element of $B$. (Or alternatively find a case where this inequality doesn't hold.)

Comment: I've tried a number of things. For example, if you assume $n=1$, you can write the whole left expression in block-matrix form (with the scalar $b_{1,1}$ being the upper-left block) and then use properties of inverses of block matrices to expand the whole thing. This leads to an expression of the form

$$\frac{b_{1,1}-C}{Q}$$

where $C$ is positive and $Q$ is a (complicated) quadratic form. So if I could prove that $Q>1$, then that would get me there, but I haven't been able to do that.

Comment: I've also tried to figure out if the maximum of this quadratic form is greater than $b_{n,n}$, but I think finding the max involves finding the eigenvalues, which seems a bit hopeless.

Comment: I've also tried proving it by induction since it is simple to show that this holds when the dimension of $A$ and $B$ are $1\times1$ or $2\times2$, but the next step is much more messy.

Comment: It seems like Woodbury may apply here, but so far it has only made everything look worse.